# InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, kaggle, image-classification

I keep getting a "graph execution error" The complete code is in the link if you'd like to see it. I don't really understand the error at all. I was trying to get the epochs running but instead, I get "1/30" and then it just stops. I checked my folders and it appears that I have all jpeg files. I'm in a corner I don't know what to do.

```
history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                              epochs=30,
                              verbose=1,
                              validation_data=validation_generator,
                              callbacks = [best_model]
                              )
```

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hvHkDusyqEsdZg5ZRVhhriZrDagpFdU6?usp=sharing

```
Epoch 1/30
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-5368c251678d> in <module>
----> 1 history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
      2                               epochs=30,
      3                               verbose=1,
      4                               validation_data=validation_generator,
      5                               callbacks = [best_model]

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     52   try:
     53     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 992, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 612, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 149, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 570, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1859, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/events.py", line 81, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 690, in <lambda>
      lambda f: self._run_callback(functools.partial(callback, future))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 743, in _run_callback
      ret = callback()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 787, in inner
      self.run()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 748, in run
      yielded = self.gen.send(value)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 365, in process_one
      yield gen.maybe_future(dispatch(*args))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
      yielded = next(result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 268, in dispatch_shell
      yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
      yielded = next(result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 543, in execute_request
      self.do_execute(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
      yielded = next(result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 306, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 536, in run_cell
      return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2854, in run_cell
      result = self._run_cell(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in _run_cell
      return runner(coro)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 68, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3057, in run_cell_async
      has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3249, in run_ast_nodes
      if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "<ipython-input-25-f51df55a1054>", line 1, in <module>
      history = model.fit_generator(train_datagen.flow_from_directory(TRAINING_DIR,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2260, in fit_generator
      return self.fit(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1409, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1040, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1030, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 890, in train_step
      loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 948, in compute_loss
      return self.compiled_loss(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 201, in __call__
      loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 139, in __call__
      losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 243, in call
      return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 1787, in categorical_crossentropy
      return backend.categorical_crossentropy(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/backend.py", line 5134, in categorical_crossentropy
      return tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
Node: 'categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits'
logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[16,5] labels_size=[16,11]
     [[{{node categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1983]
```

Comment: Would you like to show us the whole error message?  Or are we supposed to guess...

Comment: I added it. But if you'd like your free to guess.

Comment: You have 11 classes but last dense layer has 5 neurons.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75048799/typeerror-tf-test-function-missing-1-required-positional-argument-steps-pe 

You seem pretty knowledgeable do you think you could help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing this kind of coding keep the number of classes properly according to your data.
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (2,2), activation=tf.nn.relu,input_shape=(60, 40, 3)),
tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),

```
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (2,2), activation=tf.nn.relu,padding = 'Same'),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),

tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation=tf.nn.relu,padding = 'Same'),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),

tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),

tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=tf.nn.relu),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation = tf.nn.softmax)
```

])
model.summary()

tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation = tf.nn.softmax)
I have 6 classes so I gave 6. Similarly keep according to your classes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).